# Como mapear uma coluna do tipo TIME no Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Eu estou usando esse mapeamento para um campo DATETIME do SQL Server:

```
Property(X => X.DatNascimento).HasColumnName("DAT_NASCIMENTO").HasColumnType("datetime");
```

Porém possuo um outro campo que é apenas TIME que não sei como configurar:

```
Property(X => X.HoraLimiteInferiorEntrada).HasColumnName("HORA_LIM_INF_ENTRADA").HasColumnType(??????);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O tipo é [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Apenas certifique-se que você usa pelo menos o SQL Server 2008, que é a primeira versão do SQL Server que suporta o [tipo `time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public TimeSpan IntervaloMaximoAlmoco { get; set; }
```

Para *Fluent API*, use:

```
Property(X => X.IntervaloMaximoAlmoco).HasColumnName("HOR_INT_ALMOCO").HasColumnType("time");
```

Comment: E o .HasColumnType(??????) eu coloco datetime mesmo?

Comment: Não. Use `time`.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o erro que deu.

Comment: Faltou trocar o tipo, apenas. Estava `DateTime` antes.